# Селектор CSS ничего не возвращает

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup, css-selectors

Ситуация следующая - приведенный код должен выбирать данные со страницы в нужном порядке, по датам. И он это исправно делает до середины 14-го октября - то есть внутри цикла с i = 86 селектор в переменной away (по-моему на j = 4, но это не точно, матч Витязь - Автомобилист) не возвращает ничего. И далее все селекторы начинают возвращать пустоту. Любопытно, что даже при обращении к ним напрямую, не в цикле, происходит аналогичный возврат пустых значений. Вопрос в том, каким образом я могу получить эти данные? Может есть иной способ, лучше/правильнее.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ResultParser {
    private final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36";

public void getDataFromURL() {
    Document document = null;
    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.khl.ru/calendar/")
                .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assert document != null;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 282; ) {
        Elements date = document.select("#tab-calendar-all > div > div:nth-child(" + i + ") > b:nth-child(2)");
        System.out.println("DATE:" + date.text());
        i++;
        for (int j = 1; j < 12; j++) {
            Elements home = document.select(
                    "#tab-calendar-all > div > div:nth-child(" + i + ") > ul > li > dl:nth-child(" + j + ") > dd > h5 > a");
            Elements away = document.select(
                    "#tab-calendar-all > div > div:nth-child(" + i + ") > ul > li > dl.b-details.m-club.m-rightward > dd > h5 > a");
            Elements scoreOrTime = document.select(
                    "#tab-calendar-all > div > div:nth-child(" + i + ") > ul > li > dl.b-score > dt > h3");
            Elements periodScore = document.select(
                    "#tab-calendar-all > div > div:nth-child(" + i + ") > ul > li > dl.b-score > dd > ul");
            System.out.println("HOME: " + home.text());
            System.out.println("AWAY: " + away.text());
            System.out.println("SCORE OR TIME: " + scoreOrTime.text());
            System.out.println("PERIOD SCORE: " + periodScore.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отбой тревоге. Методом истеричного неконтролируемого поиска ответ был найден:

```
.maxBodySize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

в блоке получения документа расширял размер выгрузки, в которую уже попадали все данные.
То есть должно быть:

```
document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.khl.ru/calendar/")
    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
    .maxBodySize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
    .get();
```